# Openvpn3 client pickup wrong gateway

Tags: openvpn

I tried to set up an openvpn3 client on a server with two NICs one physical card and the other a tun device. I want to setup a new tun device over the existing one. But when I run openvpn start command, the openvpn3 client adds the wrong route which gateway points to the physics card's IP.

How can I disable openvpn3 client from changing route before connecting to server?